# selected options does not show. Maybe angularjs issue?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one dropdown menu, which is a normal HTML code, it includes only the Angularjs tag, because i need that to populate a second AngularJs dropdown menu. Here is the first dropdown menu:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectClass" ng-change="changed()" id="class" name="class">
```

There is a selected option, unfortunately I am not able to see it in the browser, only as source code.

Why is that ?

Comment: Where is `</select>` tag? Has it some options or not??

Comment: Of course i have select end tag and options!

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my example so you can see where your differs. To see option value in browser you have to render it. Therefore maybe your bindings are not working. BTW it is always a good idea to wrap options in object because of scoping. Now you can have many options in array when you just use ng-repeat over them.

```
   <html ng-app='app'>
    <head>
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('app',[]);
         app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
         $scope.selectClass = {
           id: 'Option 1',
           text: "Text for option A"
         };
         $scope.changed = function() {
           window.alert($scope.selectClass.value);  
         };
       });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectClass.value" ng-change="changed()" id="class" name="class">
      <option id="selectClass.id">{{ selectClass.text }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that your example is working. My differs from yours in the <option> part. I have  pure HTML and the right option is selected when i check the source code, but in the browser is not marked as such. I think that is some problem of the angularjs tags in the <select> tag. Is that possible ?

Comment: select holds the option (variable) that is selected from select dropdown. If you can get value in your controller that means that your bindings and angular itself is setup right. One thing people really suggest is to use objects to represent options because the scope may overwrite your value if it is stored in simple variable. So if the browser shows different value than one you've selected check this issue and also your console. I don't have full code to see.